# Search a multidimensional array for more than one specific value

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array that looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
            (
                [day] => Every Sunday
                [time] => 08:00
                [form] => normal
            )

    [1] => Array
            (
                [day] => Every Monday
                [time] => 10:30
                [form] => special 
            )

    [2] => Array
            (
                [day] => Every Wednesday
                [time] => 17:00
                [form] => normal
            )
)
```

I'd like to check if it contains specific days. For example, I'd like to check if it contains Monday and Sunday.

Using array_search works fine for one day. E.g. if I only want to check for Sunday:

```
array_search('Sunday', array_column($times, 'day'));
```

But it returns nothing if I pass in more than one day and attempt to search for Sunday and Monday:

```
array_search(array('Sunday', 'Monday'), array_column($times, 'day'));
```

Is there another way of doing this, preferably without iterating through everything using a for loop?

Comment: _I'd like to check if it contains several days._ Are you interested in knowing if array contains more than one Occurance OR that is contains some specific days

Comment: Hi Riggs, I'd like to check if it contains specific occurances. E.g. Maybe Tuesday and Thursday. Maybe Sunday and Monday.

Comment: You do realise that example array is not valid I suppose?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've updated now.

Comment: Stupid question, (but I always like to check these types of things) do you really mean `'Sunday, Monday'`? `'Sunday', 'Monday'` would actually make an array of "Sunday" and Monday. The example you posted makes an array with 1 element: "Sunday, Monday". I'm sure it's just a typo, but you never know.

Comment: @Chipster sorry, yes, should be ('sunday','monday'). I've edited now.

Answer (score 0):

Your array for times defines the key 'day' twice, so this array will not be valid.

try changing your input array to

```
$times = array(
    'Monday',
    'Sunday
);
```

Secondly, array_search() cannot accept an array as its first value, as it is expecting a search term please see:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

As array search returns the Key of the array of the found value, this is not what you need here, you could use:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

this will grab a unique list of values in your input array and return a key => value set with the value => count as a new array.

```
$times = array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Monday','Monday');
print_r(array_count_values($times));
```

should return:

```
array (
    [Monday] => 3
    [Tuesday] => 1
    [Wednesday] => 1
)
```

**UPDATE:**

After op gave a multidimensional array, the solution would be

```
array_count_values(array_column($array, $key));
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I cannot change the original array from a multidimensional array.

Comment: HI, the array you provided is not multidimensional, as it only contains one set of key => values, an array is only multidimensional if a value itself contains an array. Even an array like the one in my post  will be assigned keys as 0, 1, 2 etc as that is the default behaviour, array_count_values() will ignore the keys regardless of what they are, a long as they are unique.

Comment: @MHewson sorry, I've updated now with some real data.

Comment: Ah now it makes more sense. You could use the same method but instead of array_count_values($times); you could do array_count_values(array_column($times, 'day'));

Comment: Great thanks, that is returning a simple array now. So if I just want to know if there's a 'Monday' and 'Wednesday' in there, how could I do that?

Comment: There are two ways i can think of to achieve that... following on from your current flow. You could use array_keys(), followed by array_intersect() which will return an array of values only where they match your input, example: array_intersect(array('Monday','Tuesday'), $array_keys($array));   or for a single value you could use in_array($day, $array_keys($array));

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

```
print_r(array_count_values($times));
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that the needle for `array_search` is explicit, unlike `strpos`. So `Sunday` will not match a value of `Every Sunday`, assuming that `One Sunday` or `Every Sunday` may be desired to be searched for.

Since you already know the key to search for, I suggest using `array_filter`with `strpos` instead. Then you can simply use `count($filteredTimes)` to determine how many or use `array_keys($filteredTimes)` to retrieve the keys as it would `array_search`;

It will be the equivalent of using `array_column` and `array_search` or `array_count_values` or `array_keys($array, $search)`. 
But instead of only returning an array of keys (or single key) with 2 iterations, it will return the original array values that contain the desired criteria or be empty, with 1 iteration.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/uCUMr

```
$filteredTimes = array_filter($times, function($v) {
    return isset($v['day']) && (false !== strpos($v['day'], 'Sunday') || false !== strpos($v['day'], 'Monday'));
});
$matchingDays = count($filteredTimes);

var_export($filteredTimes);
var_dump($matchingDays);
```

**Result**

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'day' => 'Every Sunday',
    'time' => '08:00',
    'form' => 'normal',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'day' => 'Every Monday',
    'time' => '10:30',
    'form' => 'special',
  ),
)

int(2)
```